# Azure functions blob copy operation using start_copy_from_url fails after function ends, without any error

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

Genral info:
i am using azure durable functions, one of the activity triggers copies blobs from one storage account to anotheר using python with the v2 functions module and `blobClient`.

When trying to copy a blob from one storage account to another the copy opertion fails right after the function ends.

Now, the thing is that when the function is still running the copy operation is in a pending state,
this code does work and copy works

```py
blob.start_copy_from_url(url)
for i in range(100):
  if blob.get_blob_properties().copy.status == 'pending':
    return
  sleep(2)
```

but this code doesn't

```py
blob.start_copy_from_url(url)
```

as soon as the function ends i get a failed copy status.

I have tried using the required_sync flag when copied but that didn't work, i am not sure what else to try.

edit:
i just want to call `start_copy_from_url` and not wait for the result

Comment: What's the source blob URL you are using?

Comment: @GauravMantri SAS url

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code and the blob was copied successfully refer below:-

***Python code to copy blob from one storage account to another:-***

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def copy_blob(source_connection_string, source_container_name, source_blob_name, destination_connection_string, destination_container_name, destination_blob_name):
    # Create BlobServiceClient instances for source and destination storage accounts
    source_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(source_connection_string)
    destination_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(destination_connection_string)

    # Get a reference to the source blob container and blob
    source_blob_container_client = source_blob_service_client.get_container_client(source_container_name)
    source_blob_client = source_blob_container_client.get_blob_client(source_blob_name)

    # Get a reference to the destination blob container and blob
    destination_blob_container_client = destination_blob_service_client.get_container_client(destination_container_name)
    destination_blob_client = destination_blob_container_client.get_blob_client(destination_blob_name)

    # Start the copy operation
    destination_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(source_blob_client.url)

    # Wait for the copy operation to complete
    copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status
    while copy_status == "pending":
        copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status

    if copy_status == "success":
        return "Blob copy completed"
    else:
        return "Blob copy failed"

# Example usage
source_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconstrg39;AccountKey=xxxxeb8CflFXxxxxWgMV3XUvFdQyR3+xxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
source_container_name = "data"
source_blob_name = "devopsthreads.txt"

destination_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg30;AccountKey=xxxxxe9RtboYdCsPqo4Pgaeq8uQrD21J8N5aihuIanVIDOjqpv5TDKxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
destination_container_name = "pack"
destination_blob_name = "devopsthreads.txt"

result = copy_blob(source_connection_string, source_container_name, source_blob_name, destination_connection_string, destination_container_name, destination_blob_name)
print(result)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**With SAS URL:-**

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

def copy_blob(source_blob_url, destination_connection_string, destination_container_name, destination_blob_name):
    # Create a BlobClient instance for the destination storage account
    destination_blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(destination_connection_string, container_name=destination_container_name, blob_name=destination_blob_name)

    # Start the copy operation
    destination_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(source_blob_url)

    # Wait for the copy operation to complete
    copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status
    while copy_status == "pending":
        copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status

    if copy_status == "success":
        return "Blob copy completed"
    else:
        return "Blob copy failed"

# Example usage
source_blob_url = "https://siliconstrg39.blob.core.windows.net/data/devopsthreads.txt?sp=racwdyti&st=2023-08-21T08:14:58Z&se=2023-08-21T16:14:58Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sxxxx9Ti6BTLOHhpxxxxx"
destination_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg30;AccountKey=xxxxxxPgaeq8uQrD21J8Nxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
destination_container_name = "pack"
destination_blob_name = "devopsthreads.txt"

result = copy_blob(source_blob_url, destination_connection_string, destination_container_name, destination_blob_name)
print(result)
```

[image]

**HttpTrigger code:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="HttpTrigger")

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
   

 def copy_blob(source_connection_string, source_container_name, source_blob_name, destination_connection_string, destination_container_name, destination_blob_name):
    # Create BlobServiceClient instances for source and destination storage accounts
    source_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(source_connection_string)
    destination_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(destination_connection_string)

    # Get a reference to the source blob container and blob
    source_blob_container_client = source_blob_service_client.get_container_client(source_container_name)
    source_blob_client = source_blob_container_client.get_blob_client(source_blob_name)

    # Get a reference to the destination blob container and blob
    destination_blob_container_client = destination_blob_service_client.get_container_client(destination_container_name)
    destination_blob_client = destination_blob_container_client.get_blob_client(destination_blob_name)

    # Start the copy operation
    destination_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(source_blob_client.url)

    # Wait for the copy operation to complete
    copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status
    while copy_status == "pending":
        copy_status = destination_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy.status

    if copy_status == "success":
        return "Blob copy completed"
    else:
        return "Blob copy failed"


    source_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconstrg39;AccountKey=xxxxx7eb8CflFXM5K3bWSWgMV3XUvFdQyR3+xxxxlw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    source_container_name = "data"
    source_blob_name = "devopsthreads.txt"

    destination_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg30;AccountKey=ZxxxxPgaeq8uQrD21J8N5aihuxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    destination_container_name = "pack"
    destination_blob_name = "devopsthreads.txt"

    result = copy_blob(source_connection_string, source_container_name, source_blob_name, destination_connection_string, destination_container_name, destination_blob_name)
    print(result)

    return func.HttpResponse(result)

 return func.HttpResponse("Blob copied successfully")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the long explaintion but the thing is that I don't want to wait for the copy to end, I just want to `start_copy_from_url` and move on with the function